# Account for upper and lower case in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, module

Is there a way to account for both upper and lower case letter in python? Here's the example:

```
if 'jay' in rapper:
    print 'blah blah blah'
```

I want the if statement to be true for Jay or jay.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide more information as to what `type` `rapper` is? For lists/dicts you are better off to ensure case upon insertion, or else write your own search method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if 'jay' in rapper.lower():
    #do stuff
```

Comment: You're assuming `rapper` to be a string rather than a list.

Answer (score 3):

Just to offer an alternative (@JoelCornett's solution is nicer) you could also do:

```
if rapper in ('jay', 'Jay'):
   # do stuff
```

An advantage this approach has is that you could check for different names (though not a requirement in this case).

I am assuming that `rapper` is a string in the absence of any other information.

Comment: @Daenyth good point, but we don't know what rapper is, and I don't believe either of the other current answers could handle a list as is.

Answer (score 3):

if rapper is a list of strings

```
if "jay" in [x.lower() for x in rapper]:
    # do something
    print "done"
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to do this (assuming `rapper` is a non-null string):

```
if rapper.strip().lower() == 'jay':
    print 'blah blah blah'
```

Another option, using regular expressions:

```
import re
if re.match(r'Jay', rapper.strip(), re.IGNORECASE):
    print 'blah blah blah'
```

The above will work for `rapper =` `'jay'` or `'jAy'` or `'JAY'` or `'   Jay  '` ... etc.